# Find the maximum value of $|b|+|c|$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

Let $\mathit{f}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $\mathit{f}(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ such that $|\mathit{f}(x)|\le1$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $|x|\le1$. Find the maximum value of $|b|+|c|$. I presume that if $x=0$, then $|b|+|c|$ can't be determined, but I think I am missing an important point. Can anyone help me with a hint? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There seems to be an implicit assumption in the question, namely that it makes sense at all, i.e. that we cannot have arbitrary large $b$ and $c$ and still expect $|f(x)|$ to stay below 1. So a good first step is to check if we are even willing to believe that example. What happens if we take $b$ and $c$ equal to a 1000 (everybody's definition of a 'large' number)? Do we indeed get that $f(x)$ gets too big? Why? That should get you started

Comment: When it says "for any $x$" it doesn't mean you can pick one. You need your parabola to have *all* of its outputs for each $x \in [-1,1]$ to be at most $1.$

Comment: Note that in the function $~f(x),~$ the coefficient of $~a~$ is unspecified.  I think that the problem is poorly presented, because the value of $~a~$ affects the possible satisfying values of the coefficients $~b~$ and $~c.$

Comment: @coffeemath The coefficient of $~a~$ is unconstrained.  Re my previous comment, how do you interpret the problem?

Comment: Note that the "standard problem" asks for $|a|+|b|+|c|$. Did you perhaps have a transcription error?

Comment: @user2661923 To me it means that one has to solve the problem for each real value of $a,$ and define some function $g(a)$ to denote the maximal value of $|b|+|c|$ satisfying $f(x) \le 1$ for $|x| \le 1.$ That done, one maximizes $g(a).$

Comment: @coffeemath Nice analysis.

Comment: @coffeemath Or you can just find the max of $|b| + |c|$ over all possible values of $a$ directly (Just pointing out that conditioning on $a$ isn't necessary, though it is a reasonable first step.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried.

Express $|b|, |c|$ in terms of some $ f(x_i)$.

EG $ |c| = |f(0) | \leq 1$, with maximum achieved when $f(0) = \pm 1$.

What's an expression for $ |b|$?

Hence, find the maximum for $|b|$. When does equality hold?

Hence, show that equality can hold throughout, while satisfying $|f(x)| \leq 1$ for $|x| \leq 1$.

Thus, $ \max \left( |b| + |c| \right) = \max |b| + \max |c|$.

---

Notes:

1. As to why we choose those values of $x_i$, notice that we want to still allow for $|f(x)| \leq 1$ for $|x| \leq 1$.

   - EG Requiring $f(x_1 ) = f(x_2) = f(x_3) = 1, f(x_4) = -1$ will not work since it's not a quadratic.
   - EG Requiring $f(0.8) = 1, f(0) = -1, f(-0.5) = 1$ will not work since $f(1) > 1$.
   - This suggests that we want to focus on (at least) $f(1)$ and $ f(-1)$, alongside $f(0)$.
2. Yes, it's risky assuming that we can show $ \max \left( |b| + |c| \right) = \max |b| + \max |c|$, and in general I won't advice to do so.

   - In this case, note that $ \max |b|, \max |c|$ basically boils down to specific constraints on particular values of $f(x_i)$, so we could see if equality can hold throughout (subject to the previous note).
   - Alternatively, look at bounding $ |b+c| , |b-c|$ in terms of $f(x_i)$. This leads to an alternative solution.

> $|b+c| = \frac{1}{2} | f(1) + 2f(0) - f(-1) | \leq 2$.
>  $|b-c| = \frac{1}{2} | f(1) - 2f(0) - f(-1) | \leq 2$.
>  $|b| + |c| \leq \max( |b+c| , |b-c|) \leq 2$.

2. For the "standard problem" that I was referencing where we're maximizing $|a| + |b| + |c|$, we can extend this solution to show that
   $$ \max ( | a| + |b| + |c| ) = \max |a| + \max |b| + \max |c|. $$

> $$|a| = \frac{1}{2} | f(1) + f(-1)  - 2 f(0) | \leq 2.$$
>  Equality holds when $ f(1) = f(-1) = 1, f(0) = -1$ which occurs when $f(x) = 2x^2 - 1$ (and the negative of that).
>  We verify that this satisfies the original hypothesis.

Comment: Are you saying that the problem is workable, *as is*, even though the value of the coefficient $~a~$ is unconstrained?

Comment: @user2661923 Correct. I verified that this approach works. $\quad$ Note that even though $a$ appears unconstrained initially, we can actually do something similar to constrain $|a|$.

Comment: @user2661923 FYI I included why $|a| \leq 2$.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me understand the problem as it is.